# How to fix "TypeError: plugin is undefined" error when using VeeValidate with Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

When I add:

`Vue.use(VeeValidate);`

My Vue page shows up blank with the console error:

`TypeError: plugin is undefined`

I found the following with the same error:

[Vue plugin vee-validate not installing properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49311286/vue-plugin-vee-validate-not-installing-properly)

but I am not utilizing the => syntax anywhere in my .vue document.

vee-validate 3.0.3, Vue 2.6.10

Full main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

In my App.vue file I do include ValidationProvider as a component:

```
<script>
import CriteriaDataModel from './data-model/criteria-data-model.js';
import UserDataModel from './data-model/user-data-model.js';
import { ValidationProvider } from 'vee-validate';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      criteriaModel: CriteriaDataModel,
      completeMessage: null,
      form: {
        user: UserDataModel
      }
    };
  },
  components: {
    ValidationProvider
  }
};
</script>
```

I also tried changing my Vue initialization to this without it helping:

```
new Vue({
  render: function (h) { return h(App) },
}).$mount('#app')
```

I observed that VeeValidate has many usages of the '=>' syntax (referenced in the other stack overflow as being the problem) in the node_module, but since the intention is to use it for Vue, I question whether that is the problem.

Comment: `ValidationProvider` is a component which you should register it with `Vue.component`.
```Vue.component('ValidationProvider', ValidationProvider)```

Comment: Isn't that equivalent to listing it in the components section of the default exports in the .vue file?

Comment: [github](https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/blob/master/src/components/Provider.ts#L45) it's the source code. It's clear that `ValidationProvider` is an constructor that return by `Vue.extend` which you can create a instance with `new` or register a global component with `Vue.component`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured this out.  The default export for vee-validate seems to be null.  It worked after I changed the import to:

```
import * as VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
```